# How to handle ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a PictureBox control.  When I click the the image on the control, event handler fired.

Here is the event handler:

```
Private Sub pbImageHolder_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles pbImageHolder.Click

  Dim clickPoint As Point = MousePosition
  Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap(pbImageHolder.Image)
  pixelColor = img.GetPixel(clickPoint.X, clickPoint.Y)

  For i As Integer = 0 To img.Width
    For j As Integer = 0 To img.Height

    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that I get in this row:

```
 pixelColor = img.GetPixel(clickPoint.X, clickPoint.Y)
```

This is the exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>     Message=Parameter must be positive and < Width.
>
> Parameter name: x
>     ParamName=x
>     Source=System.Drawing

Any idea how can I fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SizeMode is the default Normal (see Hans' comment below), the MouseClick event would be a more appropriate event to handle instead of click since it will pass the mouse location for you.

Also, you need to check that the point is within the bounds of the image.

```
Private Sub pbImageHolder_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                     ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) _
                                     Handles pbImageHolder.MouseClick

  Using img As Bitmap = New Bitmap(pbImageHolder.Image)
    If New Rectangle(Point.Empty, img.Size).Contains(e.Location) Then
      pixelColor = img.GetPixel(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y)
      For i As Integer = 0 To img.Width - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To img.Height - 1

        Next
      Next
    End If
  End Using
End Sub
```

For the looping, make sure to go one less than the width and height.

You shouldn't need a Try - Catch for this error unless you don't know the range, but in this case, you know the range is tied to the size of the image.

Comment: PictureBox.SizeMode messes up this code.  As it did with the OP.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point.  The OP is also using MousePosition - that can't be good.

Answer (score 0):

a combination of defensive programming (testing for nulls and out of range variable values) and using proper try/catch blocks (you can even `catch` the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception itself if you want to try to 'fix' it if your defensive tactics 'failed').